# Можно ли остановить service, если приложение свернули?

Tags: java, android, service

Есть `Service` который запускается в `onCreate()` одной из `Activity` и останавливается по завершению задачи методом `stopSelf()`. В манифесте я прописал `android:stopWithTask="true"` что бы сервис убивался при закрытии приложения.
Вопрос такой, можно ли приостановить или убить сервис, если приложение свернули и оно находится в фоне, не используя метод `onStop()` у активности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как решение - можете пойти через `application`
У каждого сервиса есть ссылка на `Application` `service.getApplication()`
У апликейшна есть лайфсайкл, следовательно вы можете воспользоваться LifeCycleObserver'ом.
Пусть сервис будет обсервером для апликейшна, который подписывается на изменения жизненного цикла апликейшна, как только отрабатывает `onStop()` апликейшна, вы можете это отловить. Т.е. что-то на подобии
В сервисе имплементите LifecycleObserver и :

`(getApplication() as MyApplication).subscribe(this)` потом, пишите метод, который будет вызывается при переходе апликейшна в `onStop()`

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ!
Я именно с помощью `Application` все и реализовал, почему то сразу про него не подумал.